# How to swap between two images with one separate hyperlink ONLY

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hyperlink, swap

Been trying to find a solution to this but usually all methods involve mouse-hovering or mouse-clicking on the image itself rather than a hyperlink to swap the two images - or having to click on 4 separate links to view 4 different images for example.

```
    <div id="aboutus">
    <a href="#>More about us...</a>

    <img id="introimage" src="images/img1.jpg" style="display:block">
    <img id="introimage" src="images/img2.png" style="display:none"/>
    </div>
```

Simply put I would like the 'More About Us' link to swap the display for the images when clicked - or any other method that would let me swap the two images on each click.

Comment: First things first - you can't have 2 elements with the same ID.  You either need unique IDs or change it to a class.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments, you should change the IDs so they're unique or make them classes (as I have done in this example).

**HTML**

```
<div id="aboutus">
    <a href="#" class="introimagetoggle">More about us...</a>
    <img class="introimage" src="images/img1.jpg" style="display:block">
    <img class="introimage" src="images/img2.png" style="display:none"/>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $("a.introimagetoggle").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("img.introimage").toggle();
    });
});
```

You could mess about checking which image is visible and then setting the display state of each of them according to that, but toggle is simple and will suit this particular instance.

Comment: Thanks, this sorted it!